# innotifywait track changes exclude root actions

Tags: bash, io, monitoring, system-calls

I am using innotifywait to track file changes of users, and was able to effectively trace whether a file was created/edited/deleted using the innotifywait tool by logging it to a log file.

However, when there are actions performed i.e rsync, all the changes are written to the log file as well.

Here is an example of performing rsync :

```
Mon Nov 23 15:42:56 .sidebar.php.KNYJir:DELETED
Mon Nov 23 15:42:56 .sidebar.php.KNYJir:DELETED
Mon Nov 23 15:42:56 .sidebar.php.KNYJir:DELETED
Mon Nov 23 15:42:56 sidebar.php
```

Attached below is the command which I am using :

```
/usr/bin/inotifywait -e create,delete,modify,move -mrq --format %w%f
```

I then pipe it to a endless while loop to process and test if the changed file exist to determine if the file does exist or not to determine if it is a create/modify/delete action.

Is there anyway we can exclude the logging for actions performed by root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that is possible, certainly not with inotifywatch. The inotify api itself simply does not provide that information. As the manpage states:

> The inotify  API  provides  no information about the user or process that  triggered the inotify event.  In particular, there is no easy  way  for  a  process  that  is monitoring events via inotify to distinguish events that it triggers itself from those that are triggered by other processes.

What you can do is to filter based on the filename. Or, if you know the process that makes the additional changes, compare with its own logfile.